# int неправильно приводится к QString

Tags: qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int array[10]={3,5,7,2,5,9,9,5,4,1};
QString array_text="";
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    array_text.append((QString)array[i]);
}
QLabel *array_label=new QLabel(this);
QPushButton *sort_array_button=new QPushButton(this);
sort_array_button->setText("Sort Array");
array_label->setText(array_text);
setGeometry(200,200,300,300);
array_label->move(100,100);
sort_array_button->move(100,150);
setWindowTitle("Sorting Array");
```

При запуске программы на метке вместо цифр показываются какие-то странные символы. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [`QString::number()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number) , иначе говоря

```
array_text.append(QString::number(array[i]));
```

Comment: В качестве рекомендации: во избежание подобных проблем откажитесь от использования приведения типов с стиле С. Вместо этого используйте операторы С++: static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast. Заметьте, что такой код: `array_text.append(static_cast<QString&>(array[i]));` вызвал бы ошибки ещё на этапе компиляции.